# Android HttpClient thread safe

Tags: android, multithreading, httpclient

I am implementing simple HttpManager which will be used as singleton and it can executes multiples request from different threads in parallel. Could you take a look on that code and tell me if concept is ok.

```
public class HttpManager implements IHttpManager {

    private static final String TAG = HttpManager.class.getSimpleName();    
    private static final String HOST
    private static final int PORT = 80;

    private Handler mHandler; 
    private HttpClient mHttpClient;

    private static HttpManager sInstance = new HttpManager();

    public static HttpManager instance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    private HttpManager() {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(final IHttpRequest request) {   
        final String action = request.getAction();
        final List<NameValuePair> params = translateParams(request.getParams());

        (new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {                   
                    URI uri =URIUtils.createURI("http",HOST+"/"+action+".php", 
                        PORT, "", URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8"), null);                   
                    final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);

                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httpget);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if (entity != null) {
                            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                            final String text = readStream(instream);
                            Log.d(TAG, text);
                            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    request.onCompleted(text);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change it like this:

```
private static HttpManager sInstance = null;

public static HttpManager getInstance() {
    if( instance == null)
        sInstance = new HttpManager();

    return sInstance;
}

private HttpManager() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, you need to introduce a lock when you check if sInstance is null

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but Threads are expensive, so try to avoid creating them. Instead of creating one for every request, use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). In your execute method, instead of creating a Thread, create a Runnable and pass it into the Executor.

Also be careful on the Thread pool size you use. Too many threads are going to bog down your device. Also, too many simultaneous network requests are probably going to result in poorer performance, particularly on a mobile network.

Comment: I changed concept a little bit (to not execute request in parrallel, but one after one). I've just created single thread and associated his MessageQueue with Handler object. And in execute method i just do handler.post(Runnable), which will be executed one by one